# Simple way to serialize nulls as zeroes in Jackson

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

Part of my response are some BigDecimal fields and I would like to serialize these specific fields to 0 when they are null. Is there a simple way in Jackson library to achieve that (i.e. with field annotation or something similar) or is a custom serializer required here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a custom serializer (try extending StdSerializer, NullSerializer has a private default constructor...).

If you want all null fields in class to be treated this way, you can simply annotate the target class:

`@JsonSerialize(nullsUsing = NullsToZeroSerializer.class)`

If you want to do it in the whole project, create a `SimpleModule` for `ObjectMapper` and add your serializer to this module, and the module to ObjectMapper.

If you want to do this only for `BigDecimal` it may be sufficient to simply check the value passed to `serialize` method with `instanceof`.

```
public class NullToZeroSerializer extends StdSerializer<Object> {

protected NullToZeroSerializer(Class<Object> t) {
    super(t);
}

@Override
public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
    if (value instanceof BigDecimal) {
        gen.writeNumber(0);
    } else {
        gen.writeNull();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please fix link in your response. It points to the current page.

Comment: The second answer to this thread has been removed, so the link broke...

Comment: I was suspecting it's the only way. Thank's for a detailed description.